# android: emulator not resetting values completely every run

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I just am trying to understand why my android emulator does not reset values in variables every time I run the application. For example, my app involves fictional money and on the first app run I give the user some money to start and I play with it a little bit but when I re-run it, it already has the money from after I played with it. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Please show the code that's producing the unexpected values.

Comment: Its not actually any code in particular, I have experienced this with many different apps. So lets say I update a score to 5 from 0 when Im testing it. The next time I compile and run the program on the emulator (without exitting out of the emulator), the score would begin at 5 as if I left off from where I was last test.

Comment: Maybe the app intends the value to persist.  Can't tell without seeing the code.  The emulator does not wipe clean at every run.  It's like a an actual device.